# What does wrapping a type in () do and when should I use it? Golang

Tags: go

What exactly does wrapping a type in () do exactly and when should I use it? E.g. `blah.(*int)`

Comment: You should not use any syntax until you [read the documentation for it](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). Seriously, read the spec and take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org) before asking basic syntax questions. The [Go tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info) also a has a list of many other resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). Type assertions are used to extract the value in an interface type as some other type.

The expression `blah.(*int)` asserts that the type of the value in `blah` is `*int`.  If the assertion holds, then the value of the expression is the value stored in `blah` as a `*int`. If the assertion does not hold, then the expression panics.

A special form of a type assertion can be used in an assignment to test the assertion:

```
 ip, ok := blah.(*int)
```

If the value in blah is of `*int`, then the value is stored in `ip` and `ok` is set to true. Otherwise, `ip` is set to the zero value and `ok` is false.